# How to set position(margin) of BlockArrow in windows phone via c#

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-phone

As in the subject how to set position of BlockArrow in windows phone via c#.

I have tried:(indic is the name for instance of BlockArrow)

```
indic.SetValue(BlockArrow.MarginProperty, 500d); //no possibility to say which margin I meant here
```

and that:

```
indic.Margin.Left = 400d;
```

but it says:`Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do something like

```
var margin = indic.Margin;
margin.Left = 400d;
indic.Margin = margin;
```

Comment: I think it's because you can only get/set all of the Margin property at once.  So this way, we get the property, change the local copy, and then set it back.